# Laravel Jetstream - Stop multiple device login

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel 8 and Jetstream. As I can see my user can login to my website from multiple devices and access the contents. So I want to stop them. If a user is successfully logged in to a second device then they will logout from the first device. In short- users can access my content from one device at a time. No multiple device login.
In my earlier project with Laravel Breeze I have done it easily because the controller is present there. In Laravel Jetstream I am confused. Anyone, please suggest.

--- Update ------

Tried this but had no luck. Still, my user can login from two different devices

In FortifyServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
    Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
    Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
    Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

    RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->email.$request->ip());
    });

    RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
    });

//This is what I added
    Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user &&
            Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            auth()->logoutOtherDevices($request->password);
            return $user;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried many other methods and finally, I came to the conclusion that "`logoutOtherDevices`" will never work if you are using Laravel Jetstream. It may work if you apply non-standard hacks which I don't want.

So in my case, I tackled it in my way. After a user successfully logged in, they were redirected to their dashboard page. In the dashboard controller, I check the session table (in the database) and remove users' session records skipping the session of their current device.

Anyone facing such a problem can use my 100% working method. This is the example -

```
$this_device_session = \Session::getId(); //user's current session id is stored
//check in sessions table. If record exist then delete it skipping the current session.
if(DB::table('sessions')->where('id','!=',$this_device_session)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->exists()) {
   //delete their session
   DB::table('sessions')->where('id','!=',$this_device_session)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->delete();
}
return view('dashboard'); //user's dashboard page or any page you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply enable the commented `AuthenticateSession` middleware in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

```php
    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class, // --> this one
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

After the login, you should logout the other sessions.

```
    /**
     * Invalidate other sessions for the current user.
     *
     * The application must be using the AuthenticateSession middleware.
     *
     * @param  string  $password
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function logoutOtherDevices($password, $attribute = 'password')
```

Comment: In my Kernal.php, its already enabled - 


`protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];`

Comment: Then you're already good to go, that middleware handles it all.

Comment: But I can still login from two different browser at the same time

Comment: Are you logging the users out after the login?

Comment: No. Both user are logged in and can access the member's page

Comment: You must logout the other sessions, by using the `logoutOtherDevices` method after a user logs in.

Comment: where to put this "logoutOtherDevices" and how. Can you please show example code. In jetstream it is confusing

Comment: There are 2 ways to do that, either by using laravel fortify events or by customizing the `Fortify::authenticateUsing` method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-user-authentication | So before you `return $user;` you will run `auth()->logoutOtherDevices($request->password)`

Comment: can you refer me to some article's link that I can see how it is done.

Comment: I just updated the comment above ^^

Comment: No luck. I updated my question.